# Cash contract CashIssueFlow to enable only specific party to selfIssueCash

Tags: corda

I am testing out corda's inbuilt `CashIssueFlow` where a participant in the network can issue cash to itself. My Question is how can i enforce this on a contract level to only allow a specific party to self-issue cash so other participants in the node will not be able to selfIssueCash?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could write your own `Cash` contract to prevent anyone but a specific party from issuing cash:

```
override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
    requireThat {
        val allStates = tx.outputsOfType<Cash.State>() + tx.inputsOfType<Cash.State>()
        "Only DUMMY CASH ISSUER can issue cash" using (allStates.all { it.amount.token.issuer == DUMMY_CASH_ISSUER })
    }
}
```

However, it's likely that different nodes will want to accept cash from different issuers. One node may only want to accept cash from Banks A, B and C, while another node may only want to accept cash from Banks X, Y and Z.

You'd achieve this by modifying the flow logic installed on each node so that transactions involving cash not issued by specific trusted banks is rejected:

```
@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Acceptor(val otherPartyFlow: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val signedTx = otherPartyFlow.receive<SignedTransaction>().unwrap { tx ->
            // TODO: Checking of received transaction.
            tx
        }

        val ledgerTx = signedTx.toLedgerTransaction(serviceHub, false)
        val states = ledgerTx.inputsOfType<Cash.State>() + ledgerTx.outputsOfType<Cash.State>()

        if (!states.all { it.amount.token.issuer == DUMMY_CASH_ISSUER }) {
            throw FlowException("Cash not issued by trusted party.")
        }

        ...
    }
}
```